# Order Preserving bijection is the identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\preceq$ be a well-ordering on a set $X$ and let $f:X\to X$ be a bijective function. If $f$ is order-preserving, that is, $x\preceq y$ implies $f(x)\preceq f(y)$, than I have to prove that $f$ is the identity function on $X$.

I attempted to assume the opposite, but that didn't lead to anything.

My second, more promising idea, was as follows. Since $X$ is well-ordered, there exists a least element, call it $x_1$. If I manage to prove that $f(x_1)=x_1$, then I can simply consider $X-\left\{x_1\right\}$ and repeat this process to prove $f$ is the identity. I suppose I would need the Axiom of Choice to make this rigorous.

Assuming the contrary, there exists some $x_2\in X$, such that $f(x_1)=x_2$, and $x_1\neq x_2$. Obviously, $x_1\preceq x_2$. Because $f$ is order-preserving, it follows that $f(x_1)\preceq f(x_2)$, so $f(x_1)\preceq x_1$. But $x_1$ is the least element, so this all means that $f(x_1)=x_1$. Contradiction, therefore $f(x_1)=x_1$.

As I was writing this question, asking for guidance, I came up with the solution above. Is my approach correct? Is there some other interesting way to prove this?

Comment: Yes, it seems correct.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!